# Getting a Object reference not set to an instance of an object via Set-ADAccountPassword

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am getting a NullReference when trying to reset a user's password via Set-ADAccountPassword.

I make this request:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=hu" -Properties OfficePhone, Mobile, SID | Where-Object { $_.OfficePhone -eq "888888" -or $_.Mobile -eq "888888" } | Select-Object SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "HvUpJP13" -Force) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount
```

And I am getting an error:

```
+ ... bject SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-Secu ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Activ...ement.ADAccount:ADAccount) [Set-ADAccountPassword], NullReference 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands. 
   SetADAccountPassword
```

At the same time, if I remove Set-ADAccountPassword, then the user is located for this request.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=domain,DC=hu" -Properties OfficePhone, Mobile, SID | Where-Object { $_.OfficePhone -eq "888888" -or $_.Mobile -eq "888888" } | Select-Object SID 

SID                                          
---                                          
S-1-5-21-1684329652-2275368447-683485574-8603
```

Why is the request not being completed?

Comment: Remove `Select-Object SID` and it should work. It is completely unnecessary and more than likely causing this issue

Comment: Thank you so much, it really worked as expected. If you have time - could you write later why this leads to an error? All manuals contain examples using this piece.

Comment: If you were expanding the value then it would work: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SID` because a `SID` can be used to construct an `ADAccount` instance. But an object having a property with name `SID` cannot

Comment: I can post an answer later but feel free to self answer if that explanation was enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set-ADAccountPassword` is expecting an [`ADAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adaccount?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#constructors) from pipeline which can be one of these:

- Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
- Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer
- Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServiceAccount

See [**Inputs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps#inputs) section. An `ADAccount` can also be constructed from one of these:

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

See [`-Identity` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-identity) details.

When you use `Select-Object SID` in your pipeline the reference to the original [`ADUser` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) is lost causing the error you're seeing. By simply removing this statement from your pipeline the problem would be solved. As aside, you could also remove the:

```
Where-Object { $_.OfficePhone -eq '888888' -or $_.Mobile -eq '888888' }
```

And use the `AD Filter` making your query more efficient:

```bash
# Note:
#   `telephoneNumber` is the LDAP DisplayName of `officePhone`
#   `mobile` is the LDAP DisplayName` of `MobilePhone`
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(telephoneNumber=888888)(mobile=888888))' -SearchBase 'DC=domain,DC=hu' |
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'HvUpJP13' -Force) -PassThru |
    Unlock-ADAccount
```